# Way to setup Google Cloud App that creates cache and possible request time out?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have RSS feed 3rd party website that creates cache which is stored in cache folders. Every request takes 25-40 sec first time, after that it serves from cache for 9-10 mins.

Problem 1: `GAE` doesn't provide writing to file system. So how should i provide caching?

Problem 2: Request takes 25-40 sec for every time after caching times out. How should i approach this??

Is there any way to sort this out or should i need to use `Google Compute Engine` which provides both facility??

I read articles about this but no direct answer to my question. Stuck here 2 days before posting here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache on Appengine by simply sending back the necessary cache headers in the HTTP response.

Query the next results outside the user's request using a [task queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) and prepare the new data to be served in the datastore and/or memcache. Subsequent user requests can then quickly serve the latest data that's available without the setup delay.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the file system to store text, use a [TextProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) in the NDB datastore.  Give it a unique key so you can request it in the future.

This solves your caching problem, too.  Requesting an entity by its key will use the built-in [cache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache), or if it's not in the cache it will fetch it from the datastore.

Then add a cron job to update the datastore every ten minutes or so.

```
class RssFeed(ndb.Model):
    KEY = 'RSS'
    cache = TextProperty()
    last_updated = DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

    @classmethod
    def update(cls):
        # insert your code to fetch from the RSS feed
        # cache = ...
        rss_feed = cls.get_or_insert(key=self.KEY)
        rss_feed.cache = cache
        rss_feed.save()

    @classmethod
    def fetch(cls):
        rss_feed = cls.get_by_id(self.KEY)
        return rss_feed.cache
```

Call `RssFeed.update()` to update the cache and `RssFeed.fetch()` whenever you want the cached data.